# Is the product of a positive variable and a convex function also convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a convex function $f:R_{\geq0}^N\rightarrow R$ and its first order derivatives are all positive. Now I find it is difficult to prove that the convexity of the function $g(x,y)=xf(y)$, where $x\in R_{\geq0}$ and $y\in R^N_{\geq0}$. Anybody knows how to do it?

Comment: I'm curious what led you to believe this might be true. It is not.

Comment: I think you also need $f(x) \geq 0$ for your statement to hold.

Comment: It does not matter whether or not $f(x)\geq 0$, it does not hold.

Comment: Just look at the Hessian of $g(x,y)=xy$.